# Getting NoneType Error in a function that is supposed to return a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, nonetype

I am trying to extract the first letter of each string from a list of strings. I know I can do this using abstract list functions but I wanted to do it using structural recursion.

Consider the code below:

```
def acronym(los)
    if los != []:
        return los[0][0] + acronym(los[1:])
```

I get the following error:

```
builtins.TypeError: Can't convert 'NoneType' object to str implicitly
```

While I did some research on SOF about this error, I still don't understand why this function is supposed to return `None`, when `los[0][0]` is a string and `acronym(los[1:])` also returns a string.

Any suggestions?

Comment: First, fix your indentation. Second, what do you return if `los == []`?

Comment: Oh I see that if I add else: return "" , the problem is solved. Would you mind elaborating on why simply leaving the "else" part out produces the error? Is it because the function's output would then have to be either NoneType or a string (and thus Python automatically assumes that the function is supposed to return None)?

Comment: If a function doesn't explicitly `return` something, it automatically returns `None`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time `acronym()` calls itself, it does so with all but the first string in your list: `los[1:]`.

Eventually, when you're down to just one string in the list, "all but the first string" is no strings at all, so that inside the *next* call of `acronym()`, `los` is an empty list, and your `if los != []:` test fails.

Since you don't explicitly return anything in that case, Python returns `None` implicitly, which can't be concatenated with the string you've built up:

```
>>> "Hhay" + None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Can't convert 'NoneType' object to str implicitly
```